# How do I access the non-IPM_SUBTREE Public Folder Tree with WMI?

Tags: powershell, scripting, wmi, exchange-server

I'm trying to verify when the OAB (Offline Address Book) root folder for a new OAB is created with powershell.  Is there a WMI class that exposes this?  I'm using powershell, but any examples or links will do.

Answer (score 2):

If your Exchange server is Exchange 2007, then PowerShell (using the Exchange snapin) will be able to access it by running this command:

```
Get-PublicFolder \NON_IPM_SUBTREE -recurse
```

If your server is Exchange 2003, then you will need a mixture of ADSI/LDAP to query that. Reply back if its Exchange 2003.

Comment: yup, it's 03 :(... this is why I was looking for a WMI class. It's looking like my only option is going to be MAPI stuff though - any links accepted as I put off googling it myself.